# search based on two conditions textbox and dropdown list?

Tags: sql-server

```
    alter PROCEDURE K_HM_SearchFarmeragentDet
@Type varchar(50),@farmername varchar(50)   
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT MHA.sno,MHA.farmername,MHA.referencedby,HMB.Branch,MHA.area,MHA.contactno,MHA.Type from k_Master_AddHatchingFarmer MHA inner join
 K_HM_Branch HMB on MHA.Branch=HMB.Sno where farmername like @farmername+'%'  order by farmername

END
GO
```

i had written procedure like this for searching the data based on farmername but i want to search data based on farmername as well as one dropdown list of Type. type contains two values farmer and agent. if i want to search only farmers, how can i write procedure for that please help me...

Comment: What database is this? SQL Server is what it looks like.

Comment: yes,sqlserver 2005 it is.....

Comment: Can we see the code you are using to pass in this drop down... that will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  alter PROCEDURE K_HM_SearchFarmeragentDet
  @Type varchar(50),@farmername varchar(50)   
  AS
  BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT MHA.sno,MHA.farmername,MHA.referencedby,HMB.Branch,MHA.area,MHA.contactno,MHA.Type from k_Master_AddHatchingFarmer MHA inner join
  K_HM_Branch HMB on MHA.Branch=HMB.Sno where farmername like @farmername+'%' and    Type=@Type order by farmername

  END
  GO
```

Try this

Answer (score 2):

try with this, If you don't select anything from the dropdown, be sure to pass null value to the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE K_HM_SearchFarmeragentDet
@Type varchar(50),@farmername varchar(50)   
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT MHA.sno,MHA.farmername,MHA.referencedby,HMB.Branch,MHA.area,MHA.contactno,MHA.Type from k_Master_AddHatchingFarmer MHA inner join
 K_HM_Branch HMB on MHA.Branch=HMB.Sno 
where farmername like @farmername+'%'  
AND MHA.Type = ISNULL(@Type, MHA.Type)
order by farmername
END
GO
```